# parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title" API 19

Tags: java, android, android-studio, api

Tengo un problema con compatibilidad con el siguiente codigo

```
  <style name="ExpandedAppbar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    </style>
```

en especifico con esta parte

> parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title"

Ya que se implemento en la API 21, tienen algun remplazo para la API 19 
que no genere este error de incompatibilidad.

Gracias.!!!!! c;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esto necesitas tener una carpeta de 2 valores.

Uno que existe por **defecto**, y otro, tienes que crear en tu carpeta `res` y ponerle el nombre ***values-v21***.

En la carpeta de valores predeterminados, en `styles.xml`, use un tema que no sea Material Desing. Y en la carpeta `styles.xml of values-v21` que creaste, use el tema Material D.

El Smartphone seleccionara automáticamente el archivo `styles.xml` que admita. Si el teléfono es compatible con Material Design (dispositivos Lollipop+), su aplicación usará material **theme** (carpeta values-21).

si no lo hace (en teléfonos con versiones anteriores de Android), se usará la carpeta de valores predeterminados.

Comment: gracias!, entonces creo una carpeta values-21 con material D. y  styles.xml sin esta

Comment: Si, pero no borres las que ya estan ...